# How to take Different multi line inputs?

Tags: python

The other day, for the first time I participated in a coding contest and I faced an issue with taking inputs. There were ***4 sample cases*** and ***each sample case*** had n test cases. So each sample case was in the format:

- First line denotes number of test cases
- Second line denotes number of elements in array A
- Third line denotes elements of array A
- Fourth line denotes elements of array B

To make more sense, the input was (say),

```
3                      // Number of test cases
5                      // Size of array A
2 4 3 7 9              // array A
14 21 11               // array B
3                      // Size of array A
6 7 2                  // array A
9 8                    // array B
4                      // Size of array A
5 2 6 7                // array A
12 17                  // array B
```

The solution that I tried was

```
t = int(input()) # Number of sample cases
for i in t:
   n = int(input())  # Size of array A
   arr_A = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
   arr_B = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
   # Statements...
```

When I was running the code I was getting EOF error or some error. To test what was causing the error I reduced the aforementioned sample case to

```
1                      // Number of test cases
5                      // Size of array A
2 4 3 7 9              // array A
14 21 11               // array B
```

And with this input the code was running fine.

I will truly appreciate if you tell me possible ways of taking such inputs?

Comment: _EOF error or some error_ - could you be more specific? Also `for i in t` won't work.

Comment: The line `for i in t` will raise a type-error, because integers aren't iterable. You should use `for i in range(t)` instead.

Comment: Oh! In heat of moment, I missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `for i in t` should be modified to `for i in range(t)` since we need to iterate up to a certain number.

This is the approach I usually use when it comes to taking inputs.

```
t = int(input())
while t > 0:
    n = int(input())
    arrA = list(map(int, input().split()))
    arrB = list(map(int, input().split()))
    t-=1
```